# Go - How to mock SQL `SELECT`

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-sqlmock

I'm practicing testing with Go. I'm building a CRUD operation with Echo and I'm in the state of testing my service.go file. It uses a repository that is a gorm.DB which is connected to my local Postgresql.

Also, previously I tested a Create function in this service file using a similar set-up and it worked as intended! With the GetOne function, however, returns this error:

*Previously, I tested the Create function, which works with similar set-ups.*

Could anyone guide me on how to correctly mock the return value with go-sqlmock and gorm?

repository.go

```
func (r *repo) GetByID(id int) (models.Entry, error) {
    var entry models.Entry
    err := r.Db.Table("entries").First(&entry, id).Error
    if err != nil {
        return models.Entry{}, err
    }

    return entry, nil
}
```

The service.go file

```
func (s *service) GetOne(id int) (models.Entry, int, error) {
    entry, err := s.entryRepo.GetByID(id)

    if err != nil {
        return models.Entry{}, http.StatusNotFound, err
    }
    return entry, http.StatusOK, err
}
```

Here is my service_test.go file

```
func Test_GetOne(t *testing.T) {
    mockDb, mock, err := sqlmock.New()
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Failed to create mock database", err.Error())
    }

    defer mockDb.Close()

    dialector := postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        Conn:       mockDb,
        DriverName: "postgres",
    })

    db, _ := gorm.Open(dialector, &gorm.Config{})

    t.Run("Should successfully get an entry", func(t *testing.T) {
        rows := sqlmock.NewRows([]string{"all the keys"}).AddRow("all the values")

        mock.ExpectBegin()
        mock.ExpectQuery("SELECT").WithArgs(1).WillReturnRows(rows)
        mock.ExpectCommit()

        serv := InitService(db)
        
        entry, status, err := serv.GetOne(1)

        if err := mock.ExpectationsWereMet(); err != nil {
            t.Error("SQL expressions were not met", err.Error())
        }
    })
}
```